# Apostrophe encoding issue

Tags: c#, character-encoding, rss, rss-reader

I am creating a console application in C# to take a rss Link strip the title ,picture link, the link to the article and description and save it to a SQL server database.
When decoding the string to ensure that characters inside the Title or Description/Summary which could be an apostrophe gets converted from &apos to "'", and that works. What doesn't work is when I'm in the scenario below.

Scenario:
I get text from a rss feed and the rss Title I receive is as follow:
`<title>Repair to &#x201C;Using OAuth for a simple command line script to access Google's data&#x201D;</title>`
`&#x201C;` is supposed to be quotation marks.

This is then how I encode it to UTF-8

```
rss.Summary = EncodeText(rss.Summary);
public string EncodeText(string rssTitle)
{
        var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rssTitle);
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
}
```

After I encode the Title or Summary to UTF-8, the following happens:
Repair to ?Using OAuth for a simple command line script to access Google's data?
A unicode replacement (?), replaces the character where the  was supposed to be.
Any suggestions on how I can convert ’’(the apostrophe got a curve) to "(no curve). Is there another encoding decoding that I could use as I've already tried ASCII and UTF-8 and that didn't solve this particular issue.

Comment: Hey there, =). For people to help you, you want to give information about what you're doing. For example your tags say: `html, html-encode` but your code is clearly not `HTML` and not even `JavaScript` (I'm guessing it's... c#?). You can totally include those but please tell us about your server technology you're using and so on. good luck :)

Comment: Oh alsoo.. have you thought about changing `var bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(rssTitle);` to `var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rssTitle);`? I've no idea if that works because I don't know the framework but it's worth a shot.

Comment: @Elias i've updated the question to be more informative. Hope you can help

Comment: Your question is way better now :) Sadly I'm not good in that field. I still suspect though it could be related to the `Encoding.Default` part. Take a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.8) link and especially the warning that they present. Have a good one and don't give up :)

Comment: How did you get `rss.Summary` in the first place?  This should have been taken care of by your Xml parser.